# add a logo on each page of Rmarkdown html report (pagedreport package)

Tags: html, r, pagedown

I'm using the windmill template in the `pagedreport` package in R to generate a report ([Link to Package](https://pagedreport.rfortherestofus.com/articles/reports.html)). Here is a snippet of my YAML

````
---
title: "Here is my Title"
subtitle: "Here is my subtitle"
author: "Here is my name"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
output: 
  pagedreport::paged_windmill:
    front_img: Cover Page and Logo/cover.png
    logo: Cover Page and Logo/logo.svg
    logo_to_white: TRUE
    img_to_dark: TRUE
    toc: TRUE
knit: pagedown::chrome_print
toc-title: "Table of Contents"
main-color: "#6d1d26"
google-font: FALSE
main-font: "Arial"
header-font: "Arial"
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
htmltools::img(src = logo.png"), 
               alt = 'logo', 
               style = 'position:absolute; bottom:-10%; right:40%; padding:10px; width: 110px; height: 128px') 

```
````

When I run this, my logo only goes on the cover page and not on every other page in the report. Is there any way to put my logo on each page in the report?

Comment: I wonder if you found a solution. If so, could you share it pleas?